# Full Name on Patent Application

Tags: name

I am Chinese and my last name is Low, first name is Xue Ling Gina. However, a patent filed by my company displayed my name as Xue Ling, Low, ie, without my given English name. Will there be any implications? Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 2):

By way of preface, I should note that this is a bit of a low quality answer, since I couldn't find any good sources.

But nevertheless: this will almost certainly not affect the validity of the patent.

While I do not believe there are any specific provisions related to correcting the omission of part of an inventor's name, 36 USC 256 provides the rules for adding or deleting an inventor wholesale.

36 USC 256(b) provides that:

> The error of omitting inventors or naming persons who are not inventors shall not invalidate the patent in which such error occurred if it can be corrected as provided in this section.

Such a correction is relatively straightforward.

Since an inventor can be added or deleted entirely without jeopardising the patent, I would think (though cannot show for sure) that simply omitting part of a name shouldn't be any more dramatic. That is, it should be simply correctable if the need arises.

**Anecdotes**

Anecdotally, I have worked with many clients who have a lax attitude to inventors' names. Omitting middle names or using nicknames is not uncommon. As far as I know, none of them have had any negative consequences from this.